# Comparison of orthogonal complements in L^2 and H^1 spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary, and let $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H^1(\Omega)$ the usual $L^2$ and $H^1$ function spaces on $\Omega$, respectively. We call $\phi \in H^1(\Omega)$, and $\langle \phi \rangle := \{ t \phi : t\in \mathbb{R} \}$. Then, $\langle \phi \rangle$ is a closed subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$, and thus, it is well known from the Hilbert space theory that we deduce the following two orthogonal decompositions: the first one is
$$
H^1(\Omega) = \langle \phi \rangle \oplus M_{1}, \quad \mbox{and} \ \int_\Omega \nabla \phi \nabla v dx + \int_\Omega \phi v dx = 0, \quad \forall v \in M_1,     
$$
and the second one is
$$
L^2(\Omega) = \langle \phi \rangle \oplus M_{2}, \quad \mbox{and} \ \int_\Omega \phi v dx = 0, \quad \forall v \in M_2.
$$
Then, the question is that: can we prove $M_1 \subset M_2$ ? I believe that $\int_\Omega \nabla \phi \nabla v dx = \int_\Omega \phi v = 0$ for all $v\in M_1$. How do we prove it ?

Comment: No, there's no reason for this, these are different scalar products. For example, when $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and you use Fourier transforms, then orthogonality in $H^1$ means $\int (1+t^2)\widehat{f}\widehat{g}=0$, and you can certainly cook up functions that satisfy this but $\int \widehat{f}\widehat{g}\not= 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's a nice observation. I agree with you. When considering the Fourier transformed version, integrated functions for the inner products are algebraic, so it's easier for us to find that my assertion is false. Thank you again for your helpful comment.